# Laravel eager loading issue with findOrFail()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Why to I get multiple results for this? I just want the "contacts" for the given client id. Not for all clients.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id)->with('contacts')->get();
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `findOrFail()` finds a single result for you instead of returning a collection. What that means is that it already does a `get()` call for you. So you can't add another `get()` after that. If you do, you'll get weird results as you noticed because you're essentially building a new query.

That also means that you don't need to eager load anything. The reason eager loading is good is because it allows you to fetch data for multiple objects in a single query. But you only have one object here anyway - so it doesn't really matter.

You could easily do just `$client = Client::findOrFail($id);` and then `$client->contacts` later, when you need the contacts. It won't make your performance worse.

And if you only want the contacts, not the client, you could easily do this: `$client = Client::findOrFail($id)->contacts;`

Comment: very true, i bascly asked the same question a while ago, findorfail will eagerload without using ->with (at least in my case) anyway i thing it could be work like this too Client::with('contacts')->findOrFail($id);

Comment: Thanks, and how do I access the "contacts" within the blade.view? `{{ Form::model($client, …                                                {!! Form::text('contact->name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
`

Comment: If you have multiple contacts, just do a `@foreach ($client->contacts as $contact)` and go from there.

Comment: I have just one contact. But it changes every year.

Answer (score 4):

While Joel Hinz response is correct, you can still have eager loading in this query.

Just do:

```
$client = Client::with('contacts')->findOrFail($id);
```